# No module named 'flask_security'

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, package, flask-security

**I have already installed flask-security,however I get an import error.
Here is the import line**

```
from flask_security import *
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask import  request
import json

from controller.functions import *

import flask_security
```

**It returns this error:**

```
  from flask_security import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_security'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip3 install Flask-Security
```

Comment: I have already installed flask_security by pip install .. but it shows same error

Comment: which python version u are using

Comment: version python 3.8.0

Comment: use python3.7. python3.8 is not yet stable

Comment: I use for my project 3.7 .. but  still the same error